# How to check whether have same element in two arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  
b = [1,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

`a` array has `1` and `b` array has `1` too. So they have the same element.

How to compare them and return `true` or `false` with ruby?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers and imo are discourteous to those still working on answers. The point is: there's no hurry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intersection of two arrays can get using & operator. If you need to get similar elements in two arrays, take intersect as

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  
b = [1,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

and taking intersection

```
u = a & b
puts u
# [1]

u.empty?
# false
```

Comment: You've already posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32450709/477037), no need to duplicate it.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `a & b` is empty:

```
a & b
# => [1]
(a & b).empty?
# => false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many elements per Array, doing an intersection (`&`) can be an expensive operation. I assume that it would be quicker to go 'by hand':

```
def have_same_element?(array1, array2)
  # Return true on first element found that is in both array1 and array2
  # Return false if no such element found
  array1.each do |elem|
    return true if array2.include?(elem)
  end
  return false
end

a = [*1..100] # [1, 2, 3, ... , 100]
b = a.reverse.to_a # [100, 99, 98, ... , 1]
puts have_same_element?(a, b)
```

If you know more beforehand (e.g. "array1 contains many duplicates") you can further optimize the operation (e.g. by calling `uniq` or `compact` first, depending on your data).

Would be interesting to see actual benchmarks.

**Edit**

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |bm|
  bm.report("by hand") {have_same_element?(a, b)}
  bm.report("set operation") { (a & b).empty? }
end

Rehearsal -------------------------------------------------
by hand         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000014)
set operation   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000095)
---------------------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

                    user     system      total        real
by hand         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000012)
set operation   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000131)
```

So, in this case it looks as if the "by hand" method is really faster, but its *quite a sloppy method of benchmarking* with limited expressiveness.

Also, see @CarySwoveland s excellent comments about using sets, proper benchmarking and a snappier expression using `find` (`detect` would do the same and be more expressive imho - **but carefull as it returns the value found - if your arrays contain falsey values like `nil` (or `false`)...**; you generally want to use `any?{}` here).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is also so good. But I don't know how expensive the `&` can cost? Maybe that method cost much time than `each` and `include`.

Comment: see the benchmark for the given scenario :) Like that it is easy to play through with your given data. In any case, optimizations like that do only make sense imho if you have a lot of data and performance is an issue. Otherwise choose what reads better to you.

Comment: A very good answer. Thank you very much! It is a good way to test which method is better. It seems that `&` is really expensive when the array is too big.

Comment: You need to be careful with benchmarks. `by_hand` works well for your benchmark because the first elements of `a` and `b` are the same. Better to use a variety of larger randomized arrays. Also, `array2.include?(elem)`, which you do until you find a match in `array1`, is extremely inefficient, since you repeatedly traversing `array2`. Better: `require 'set'; s2 = array2.to_set; array1.find { |e| s2.include?(e) }`. Set lookups--effectively hash lookups--are extremely fast. My guess that this would be faster than set intersection in most cases.

Comment: Try benchmarking with `a = Array.new(n) { rand m }; b = Array.new(p) { rand q } for a few combinations of `n`, `m`, `p` and `q`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland benchmarking is always hairy, if the conditions are not known. Thats why i proposed `uniq` (probably `to_set()` is even more performant and gives the benefits you described). Also, if we know that data can be sorted, we can spend a lot of brains into getting faster. Feel free to add an Update to the answer mentioning your approach using sets (i might find the time to do it myself - i might not, and you get reputation for accepted edits :) ). Thanks a lot for your thoughts on the issue!